# Algolia's instant search pagination not returning the correct pages

Tags: algolia

I've created an index with 2166 objects in it. In the configuration, I have this:

```
cProjectSearch.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.hits({
        container: '#hits-container',
        hitsPerPage: 200,
        templates: {
            item: getMustacheTemplate('hit'),
            empty: getMustacheTemplate('no-results')
        }
    })
);

cProjectSearch.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.pagination({
        container: '#cp-pagination-container',
        scrollTo: false
    })
);
```

When the search starts, it returns the 1st 200 results on page one. But the pagination widget only shows:

```
1 2 3 4 5 › »
```

and when I go to to page 5, it shows:

```
« ‹ 1 2 3 4 5
```

Pages 6 - 10 are not shown.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The is the default behaviour in Algolia, the total number of hits return is set to 1000 for performance reason. That's why you only have 5 page (200 hits * 5 pages). But you can override this parameter with the settings `paginationLimitedTo`, you can find more informations about it [in the documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/paginationLimitedTo/).

Also note that the `hits` widget doesn't accept the `hitsPerPage` attribute. You can pass it through the `searchParameters` attribute on the `InstantSearch` instance instead you can find more informations about it [in the documentation](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/instantsearch.html).

```
instantsearch({
  appId: "xxx",
  apiKey: "xxx",
  indexName: "index_name"
  searchParameters: {
    hitsPerPage: 200
  },
});
```

Comment: Samuel, I am looking at the documentation at https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v1/documentation/#infinite-hits and in the example it shows the hitsPerPage goes with the hits widget.

Comment: Yep you are right my bad! That's because you are using the v1 of InstantSearch. On the v2 you need to use the `searchParameters` attribute instead. https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/widgets/hits.html